# Get comments with all nested replies

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress post with its comments (with nested replies), like this structure:

```
POST
-Comment
--Reply
---Reply
--Reply
---Reply
----Reply
-----Reply
-Comment
--Reply
--Reply
---Reply
-Comment
```

How can I use get_comments (or other function) in order to have an array of top level comments with nested replies (with possible other nested replies)?

Comment: check this. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments

Comment: just cheked. no way to get comments with nested replies with nested replies ecc.

Comment: This, https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments. It supports 'max_depth'.

Comment: i tried to user wp_list_comments but i don't need to print any HTML, just need an array of comments and for each a nested replies (with possibile other nested replies)

Comment: Well, then have you tried WP_Query? You can create your custom query and get desired data.